# Best function to preserve information after decreasing color depth?

Tags: information-theory, colorings

Let's assume, I have a grayscale image that every pixel represented with 8 bits. I want to quantize (decrease [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)) the image into 2 bits. Hence, I need a function as $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $A\in \left[0,255\right]$ and $B \in \left[0,3\right]$. Simplest way to define function $f$ is

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & 0   \leq x \leq 63 \\
1,  & 64  \leq x \leq 127 \\
2,  & 128 \leq x \leq 191 \\
3,  & 192 \leq x \leq 255 \\
\end{cases}
$$
where the histogram is divided equally.
However, this function is not a good candidate to preserve information. For example, if the grayscale image has only values between 0 and 40, then quantized image will not have any information at all. In order to increase entropy (average information) we can divide histogram based on number of pixel values. For instance, for a given image if 1024 pixel has value between 0-37, 1024 pixel has value between 38-100, 1024 pixel has value between 101-180 and 1024 pixel has value between 181-255 in 64x64 image, then we can use the function $q$ which is

$$
q(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & 0   \leq x \leq 37 \\
1,  & 38  \leq x \leq 100 \\
2,  & 101 \leq x \leq 180 \\
3,  & 181 \leq x \leq 255 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Does the function $q$ is the best function to minimize quantization error and preserve most information in general for the given image?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)#Multiple_thresholds

Comment: "Depends", first and foremost on what you are trying to achieve. There is *image impression*, and there is *pixel value* - and even with the latter there can be more to it "2 bits" when using 2 bit/pixel.

Comment: My goal is to preserve maximum information(in terms of information theory) of original image after quantizing a single image.